# How am I notified about a new GPG message?

Tags: gnupg

I'm reading a little about GPG and keypair (public/private keys).
I'm trying to understand the basic mechanism but I do have a question. If someone sends me a file (using my public key), where will I receive it? I mean, how am I notified that someone sent a file to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPG doesn't handle message delivery, only encryption. A lot of the features assume the file will be sent by email, and some email programs have built-in gpg support, but you can use any file delivery system you like.

Comment: Oh, okay. So, if I encrypt some file with some public key (executing something like person1:~# gpg --encrypt --recipient 'person2@abc.com'' test.txt) it only means that this file will be encrypted in a way that only that 'person 2' can decrypt, using his own private key, correct? The delivery system is up to me, correct? I could use some features like enigmail for extra-security, right?

Comment: Yes, that's the basic usage, it outputs a file that you can send to anyone as long as you had their correct public key. Enigmail doesn't provide any additional security, it just integrates GPG with thunderbird so you don't have to manually attach the file.

Comment: Okay then. One more question: I can only send encrypted and signed email to people who also uses the same system (who also has a public key) or is there any system to deliver a protected message to anyone?

Comment: Using the other person's public key is the main way. There's another set of options that lets you just use a passphrase, but if you use that then you need some way to make sure the recipient knows the passphrase.